# Importing matplotlib before tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

When the `import matplotlib` call is placed just before the `import tensorflow` call (as shown in [this example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough#configure_imports)), the following error is generated:

```sh
~$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct  8 2019, 13:06:37) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot
>>> import tensorflow 
[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:61] This program
requires version 3.8.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but 
the installed version is 2.6.1.  Please update your library.
If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers 
are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  
(Version verification failed in "bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/
tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.pb.cc".)
terminate called after throwing an instance of
'google::protobuf::FatalException'
  what():  This program requires version 3.8.0 of the Protocol 
Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 2.6.1.  
Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself,
make sure that your headers are from the same version of 
Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  
(Version verification failed in "bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/
tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.pb.cc".)
Abandon (core dumped)
```

The import work when the order of the two calls is swapped (i.e. `import tensorflow` before `import matplotlib`). I want to understand what is causing this error and what are the other instances where similar error might be generated.

Comment: Does this persist if you install (upgrade) the following packages? `pip install --user --upgrade tensorflow matplotlib` & `sudo apt install libprotobuf-dev`

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2903 Here they say to uninstall/purge protobuf, then make sure to delete remaining old files in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, then install it.